# How do I get a string array from a IntFlag with multiple values?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying have an IntFlag enum and have the result come as a string array.

```
from enum import IntFlag

class BitShift(IntFlag):
    Bit8 = 0x80
    Bit7 = 0x40
    Bit6 = 0x20
    Bit5 = 0x10
    Bit4 = 0x8
    Bit3 = 0x4
    Bit2 = 0x2
    Bit1 = 0x1

bitshiftval = BitShift(0x84)

print(bitshiftval)
```

And the result I get is:

```
BitShift.Bit8|Bit3
```

But I would like to get a string array back like:

```
['Bit8','Bit3']
```

I could do a substring then split on pipe to an array but there must be an easier way to convert the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
bitshiftval = BitShift(0x84)
result = [member for member in BitShift._member_names_ if member in str(bitshiftval)]
```

printing the result:

```
['Bit8', 'Bit3']
```

Comment: That is **exactly** what I was looking for, I was trying to iterate over the enum but I didn't know that I could use _member_names_ much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the __ str__ method for the class so that it creates a list with the string representation of the bit numbers just as you wanted. Then you just return the list's string representation

```
def __str__(self):
    bit_list = []
    # logic for creating the bit string representation

    return f"{bit_list}"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```py
def get_enum_value_names(enum):
    return str(enum).split('.')[1].split('|')
```

What this function do?

- step before 1: you give the enum object (not cls) as the only input.
- step 1: calls `str(enum)` in the function. result must be like this:
  `TestEnum.MEMBER1|MEMBER2|...`
- step 2: it removes `TestEnum.` from `TestEnum.MEMBER1|MEMBER2|...` by using
  `str.split`. at first name converts to a list of string with splitting `.` and
  then takes the second item.
- step 3: splits names. names in string, splitted by `|` char, so we can use
  `str.split` again.
- step after 3: returns the result